# Phonegap:Open app(html page) after clicking upon back button in an external site

Tags: cordova, redirect, android-studio, hyperlink, external-links

How can i navigate back to a page in my android app after loading an external site.

1.Open app

2.In app user will go to an external link

3.External site has link,which take the user back to app.

How can i go to my application .
I have tried to give "file:///android_asset/www/package.html" in href but its not working at all .
Please suggest me and thank you in advance.,

Answer (score 0):

1. First to open an external url in the users default browser (Install the InAppBrowser plugin) use the window.open('http://www.yoururl.com', '_system');
2. To open your app from any browser install the [Custom URL scheme Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)
   launch your app by a link like this: <a href="mycoolapp://">Open App</a>

In config.xml of plugin change the value 
      <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="mycoolapp" /> 
to 
      <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="YOUR_CUSTOM_VALUE" />

Comment: I have done following the steps,but i am getting an error,while clicking upon open App button,Its showing 

Application Error
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME(mycoolapp://).
Please suggest me.

Comment: But i am getting error ,while running this code in cmd
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=mycoolapp
can you plz tell me why the error "Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project" is coming?

Comment: Remove the plugin and add it again